# C# PuppeteerSharp Redirection from Cloudflare Waiting Room is blocked

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, puppeteer

The site I'm trying to explore with Puppeteer is protected by a Cloudflare page that analyzes the browser. It appears that there is some problem when using `GoToAsync` - the Cloudflare waiting room is endlessly updating, but does not block access. As soon as I close the application (= close the CDP session), the redirection is immediately completed successfully. If I open the tab manually and type in the URL, the check is also successful. Either Cloudflare somehow understands that the browser is automated, or there is a problem in Puppeteer. How can we understand this?

In addition, if you create a new tab and load the page, then continue execution from the line `IPage page = await PuppeteerHeadful.NewPageAsync();`, the check will be successful.

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
PuppeteerHeadful = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions {
    Headless = false,
    Devtools = false,
    Browser = SupportedBrowser.Chrome,
    DefaultViewport = null,
    Args = new[] {
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"
    }
});

IPage page = await PuppeteerHeadful.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync(url);
```

- URL for example: https://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/check-lookup/WVWMP7AN2BE710202
- .NET version: 6.0
- PuppeteerSharp version: 14.0.0